# Laravel register and log in via phone number and SMS confirmation

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, sms

I want to make a test-project where User can register just by setting a phone number and a password. On next step, I want a package or smth like that, that will send an SMS to this number with a confirmation code. So, after User enters this code, it became registered, authenticated and redirected to homepage.

Any suggestions on what components/libraries/packages I have to use and how to modify standard Laravel registration/authentication? 
Thanks!

Comment: have a look at https://www.twilio.com/sms

Comment: As @HH stated, Twilio will be able to help you with this. You'd also have to set up a middleware to prevent a login until the number has been authorised.

Comment: But, for now, let's say I don't want to make all this SMS stuff. I just want to change the basic Laravel auth, so it will not require email at all, but just a phone number (login) and password. Any ideas of how to rewrite that stuff?
Thanks!

Comment: this guide changes email to username but you can use phone_number instead: http://laraveldaily.com/auth-login-with-username-instead-of-email/

Comment: you can then create a middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware to check if the user status is `registered` or extend the `LoginController` that comes with Auth and add to the `login` method to achieve the same result (i'd prefer Middleware)

Answer (score 7):

You can follow the below steps to login with either username, email or phone. I have also included slug and avatar for extended usage. However you can edit and change them as per your needs.

Migration

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('phone')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->boolean('gender');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

In your Auth/RegisterController modify as follows

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:20|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required|string|max:15|unique:users', //you can also use required|regex:/[0-9]{10}/|digits:10 as per your needs
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|dumbpwd|confirmed',
            'gender' => 'required|bool',
        ]);
    }

protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if($data['gender'])
          {
            $avatar = 'male.png';
          }
        else
          {
            $avatar = 'female.png';
          }

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'slug' => str_slug($data['username']),
            'avatar' => $avatar,
        ]);
    }
```

Now in your logincontroller add this

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
      {
        if(is_numeric($request->get('email'))){
          return ['phone'=>$request->get('email'),'password'=>$request->get('password')];
        }
        elseif (filter_var($request->get('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          return ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')];
        }
        return ['username' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')];
      }
```

I haven't included the model and views as they are easy. All you need is to add the new column fields to the model array and add extra fields on the registration form for username, phone, gender and avatar.

On your login view form, make the input type as text where you can either enter email, username or phone and password field remains the same.

You can further easily extend this to make user activation via code or link using any one of the below packages. I use email activation using https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel-email-confirmation which works wonderful.

I haven't tried phone verification and activation using a code, but found few packages that could help you https://github.com/phonedotcom/sms-verification-laravel

There are number of packages like twilio, google 2 step verification and many other that you can search on github or packagist. Hope this helps. Happy Coding!