# Laravel Register / Login using Mobile number only

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am in process of developing an project by which user can register/sign in using only mobile number (no password ) and once user enters mobile number it should go to otp(One time Password) screen and then when otp verifies, then he can login in.

How to implement, password less mobile number based otp auth system. Basically, i couldn't figure out where to start and how to implement. I already have sms service provider.

But couldnt find how to implement this with the default auth system. I understand that the question doesn't been broad, but i just started the auth system and stuck without knowing how to implement this.

As laravel is fully based on username/email and password based login. I couldnt understand or figure our how to implement Mobile number , OTP base login alone.

Comment: This question is too broad. Stackoverflow is a not a website to help you implement something as complex as a password-free SMS authentication system... You need to research and implement you own solution, and if you have specific errors, then you may ask a specific question. Also, what is `otp`? I haven't heard that acronym before; perhaps explain what that is/provide a reference to that.

Comment: If you are using just a mobile number without any password, I hope there is no senstive information being stored! Are you actually authenticating when they enter their mobile? Or are you trying to send the user an auth token via sms?

Comment: Otp means ONE TIME PASSWORD, by which when a user gives a mobile number as input and he gets a password as text message. And then he needs to enter it back to login @TimLewis

Comment: @Spholt Yes, i need to authenticate when they correct otp. Steps as follows , 1 Step - User enters mobile number, 2 Step - User gets One time password to their mobile via text message, 3 Step, user will enter the password on the screen and then they press submit. Thus it get verified, and once otp is validated user will be loged in

Comment: Ah, right, that makes sense, kinda like a two-factor authentication code sent via SMS, but bypassing the initial requirement for username/password. Unfortunately, the question is still too broad. You seem to have a good idea of the process required, so try making the views/routes/controllers to handle the individual steps, and worry about the actual authentication logic once you have that sorted.

Comment: @TimLewis Understood, but how to use methods like this "Auth::user()->id" as if we dont use default auth system ?

Comment: If you figured all the other logic out to login a user via this OTP, then `Auth::user()` would be aware of the logged in User and `Auth::user()->id` would function as normal. Until you've actually logged in, `Auth::user()` will return `null`. Don't worry about the problem until it actually is a problem :)

Comment: understood, I will check and will update asap @TimLewis

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a token, store it on your database along with the phone number and send it to the number. 
Like:

```
PhoneToken::create(['phone' => '...', 'token' => Str::random(10)]);
```

When the user confirms with the token you can go to the database and check if the token belongs to that number, if so authenticate the user.

```
if (PhoneToken::check($phone, $sentToken)) {
    $user = User::wherePhone($phone);
    Auth::login($user);
} ...
```

Important: remove unnecessary fields from the user migration and add the phone number field.

Comment: I understand this overall, but how to use "auth" of laravel to this ? How to change the default auth system of Larevel to adapt this ? For example in default system we can auth::user(id) to get their id, but how that would be possible in above suggested ? Basically, how to authenticate user, when they enters OTP ?

Comment: @Spholt said it all

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you wont be using much of the default `AuthController` for this as that will expect some form of username/password combo.

You can however use the `Auth` facade by doing whatever authentication checks you want and then calling the `login()` method like so:

```
// identify your user with your credentials (OTP)
$user= User::where('password', $password)->get();

// If you have a user, authenticate them
if ($user) {
    // Authenticate the user
    Auth::login($user);
}
```

This is very bare bones but you can read more here
(https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

Comment: So  i can bypass the default auth and use above mentioned ?

Comment: `Auth` can be used from pretty much anwhere within your Laravel application by including it `use Auth;`. In essence, you are only bypassing the `Auth::check()` call which expects the username and password and jump straight into telling the application to authenticate the given user.

Answer (score 0):

You will need AJAX and PHP to send OTP code and then you need to validate it with PHP session data.

The generated OTP code should be stored in PHP session variable. 
And session data should verified with the entered OTP is correct or not.

So, its long way to write you code or a class, you need to search and create something then ask for help.

I think many here will be glad to help you.

Here is a nice example : [OTP SMS Mobile Verification in PHP](https://phppot.com/php/how-to-implement-otp-sms-mobile-verification-in-php-with-textlocal/)

Comment: I know, i am just asking for the blue print for the process not the whole code. Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: @Arvindh for processing your answer is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883060/laravel-register-and-log-in-via-phone-number-and-sms-confirmation

Comment: Nope, the suggested link has concept saying phone number and password. Not phone number and OTP alone.

Comment: @Arvindh I know its not complete answer of your question but will give you good ideas where and how to start, Also Laravel has examples on teir site too : https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-login-with-only-mobile-number-using-laravel-custom-auth